# WhatsApp web and desktop app displaying broken QR codes

Tags: windows, whatsapp, qr-code

I recently bought a new laptop and when I tried to set up the WhatsApp Desktop app, the QR code won't scan on my phone. The same is the case with WhatsApp Web as well. I tried doing the following things but still didn't work out:

- Trying WhatsApp Web with a different browser
- Clearing cookies and cache
- Restarting the computer

I think the problem is with the QR code that is being displayed on my new laptop. It appears to be broken since there are white spaces where they shouldn't be as shown in the image. This happens with both the WhatsApp Desktop app and the WhatsApp web.

[image]

What might be the reason for this and how to fix it?

PS: WhatsApp Web works fine on my old laptop. So it's definitely not a problem with the Android app on my phone.

[Click here to see an example of non-defective WAW QR Code to notice the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqIWW.jpg)

Comment: No Idea, but I have the same problem BUT its just the app. The browser works fine for some reason

Comment: I faced a similar issue without driver updates help me solve
https://youtu.be/fNmCdSXguhQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your windows update there is a list of optional updates which can be used when you have a specific problem. Select the one with Intel Display and download it. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Installing beta drivers fixed this for me: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/30522/Intel-Graphics-BETA-Windows-10-DCH-Drivers

Answer (score 10):

**Disable hardware acceleration in Chrome:**

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Click "Customize and Control Google Chrome" > Settings.
3. Click on "Show advanced settings" and scroll to the System section.
4. Uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available" and restart Google Chrome.

This fixed it for me

Comment: It solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: It solves the problem for browser, but not for the App. I am using an Intel i5 11500 based system and updating display drivers  using [Intel® Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html) solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If **Chrome** or **Edge** :
In settings, disable "`Use hardware acceleration when available`"

If **Whatsapp Desktop** :
Change `Run this program in compatiblity mode for` "**Windows 7**"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a new HP Spectre 360 with 11th Intel generation. 
I solved the problem by using the Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on a clean install of a new pc build with Intel UHD 750 (INTEL i5 11600k). It happened on the QR web and desktop whatsapp app and discord.

While disabling the hardware acceleration solved the issue, it may come with a performance hit for other situations, so I thought it might be related to the graphics driver.

Windows insists on replacing the driver with its own, so I disabled this behavior by *enabling* the 'Do not include drivers with Windows Update' policy with the group policy editor (available only on pro version)

In this site you can find detailed steps : https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-automatic-driver-updates-windows-10?amp

Then I installed the updated driver directly from Intel. After that the codes worked fine everywhere and I could keep the hardware acceleration.

Comment: I had the exact situation on a fresh Windows 11 build using i5 11500 on Whatsapp app from Microsoft store. Disabling the hardware acceleration in Chrome or Edge would show QR correctly, but I wanted it to use the App. Tried many things including changing various display settings but none worked. Finally, I chose to update the display drivers using [Intel® Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html) and the problem got resolved. Now the QR code shows perfect in Whatapp App installed from Microsoft Store.