# "Broken" QR on Whatsapp Desktop

Tags: remote-connection, whatsapp, qr-code, web-whatsapp

I just got a new Laptop and downloaded Whatsapp, but my phone can't connect to it because for some reason my QR code looks like this: [image: Broken QR]

It has like white strips all over it, and generally it's unreadable.
It also appeared like that on Whatsapp Web, but I managed to fix it by turning off the "Use hardware acceleration when available" in chrome's settings.

I still prefer much more the desktop version but can't find a way to fix it.

Comment: Try to go to windows settings-> display settings, and set the dpi scaling to 100%

Comment: There is a similar post. Take a look at [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1606458/whatsapp-web-and-desktop-app-displaying-broken-qr-codes)
.

Comment: @1NN I didn't manage to find where I change it to 100% but did try to change it in the app's compatibility settings... it didn't work though.
Do you have some more ideas? I Really want to fix this :(

Comment: @efe373 That's the first post I looked at but there is no solution there for the whatsapp-desktop problem :/