# SOLVED | Images are rendering broken

Tags: image-processing

I got a new computer for Christmas. I love it! But then I went on scratch and saw that the blocks were rendering broken. Later I wanted to log in to WhatsApp web and the QR code was broken. It's happening to websites (?) and web apps. Here are some pictures.

My (now expired) W̶h̶a̶t̶s̶a̶p̶p̶ ̶W̶e̶b̶ Discord QR code:

[image: My (now expired) Discord QR code]

My scratch code for my FPS counter:

[image: My scratch code for my FPS counter]

Comment: Is this a Computer with Windows and a new nVidia card?

Comment: What's the computer model?

Comment: Have you updated all of your drivers?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1606458/714576)

Comment: @EugenRieck Nope

Comment: @harrymc 

Comment: @spikey_richie 1NNs comment fixed it but yeah

Comment: @harrymc yes, yes it did